# Word or phrase to describe running fingers through one's hair

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Consider two women walking in a park on a cold windy evening talking with each other. As one of them talks, the other one listens intently and runs her fingers through her long hair, hair which was moving lazily in the wind.

Is there a word or phrase for such an act of moving one's fingers through one's hair? (Though actually interested in/concerned about what the other person is saying..)

Comment: "idle fingercombing"? That's not a set phrase, though.

Comment: Thanks @Kris..but I wanted something with a bit of a poetic touch to it..what u suggested seems somewhat formal..

Comment: Your own phrase, "running her fingers through her (long) hair," is probably the most common way of saying this. You can add an adverb like "slowly" or "distractedly" or "sensuously" to make it more specific.

Comment: "something with a bit of a poetic touch" -- See also [writers.se] Good Luck.

Comment: If someone is worried they often *fiddle* with things, and that would seem more appropriate than *play* which suggests enjoyment or pleasure. I agree this isn't really on-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how specific you want the phrase to be, you could say that she was "[playing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/play)" with her hair.

> To toy or fiddle around with something
>
> - She idly played with her long hair, which was moving lazily in the wind

Answer (score -2):

I recently came across the word *cafuné* (cah-foo-neh). It's a Portuguese word, possibly borrowed from Kimbundu, a Bantu language.

> **cafuné**: the act of fondling someone's hair ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cafun%C3%A9))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which foreign language? And why do you think a non-English word is needed? Collins defines it: fazer cafuné em alguém “to stroke somebody's hair” Not quite the same situation described in the question.